# Session Storage is not removed

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot remove the session Storage value.
Currently I'm getting the user id in "user_ID" using this code in dashboard page after login.
    sessionStorage.setItem("user_ID", data[0].user_id);

But after click the signout button I used this code to clear the seesion

```
sessionStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.removeItem("user_ID");
```

but if I paste the link in browser,there the session value again shows?
Is any another way to unset the sessionStorage value?

Comment: I would check to make sure that those lines are actually getting called.  Also make sure the domains are the same where the values are getting set as when they are getting cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you write these function inside submit button